# Days as a time series?

Tags: time, time-series, tableau-api, timeserieschart

Is there a way to get Tableau to recognize generic days as a time series?

I have scientific data that involves measurements taken over twelve days. It doesn't matter what those actual dates are - I don't know if it was January or October, last month or five years ago. What matters is seeing them in order from Day 1, Day 2, Day 3, and being able to use time series functionality like animation and such. My gut instinct is to give it fake dates like January 1, 2018, January 2, etc and then change the alias, but is there a more elegant solution?

Example:
Sample A
 Day 1: 80
 Day 2: 116
 Day 3: 152

Sample B
 Day 1: 30
 Day 2: 65
 Day 3: 189

Sample C
 Day 1: 45
 Day 2: 103
 Day 3: 162

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's true that the actual date doesn't matter, then the best thing to do would treat your days as a series of numbers on a timeline. Afterall, that's what Tableau does with dates. Of course, Tableau's treatment of dates isn't that simple, but for this example, we can simply treat our dates as numbers.

I went ahead and create a small data set to simulate your scenario.

[image]

In order to get the split the number out of our [day] column, we use Tableau's SPLIT function.

[image]

The delimiter is a space or " " and we want the second value returned from the split. We also want this to be an **Int**eger, so we wrap the whole function in the INT function.

Finally, you'll be able to see those values spread across your days.

[image]

By adding our new [Day Number] to the filter you can use the slider to be selective with the days you display.

Comment: Ah-HA! Thank you! I didn't realize that the animation would work on any number (when I tried this with another field, I must have had something else wrong because it didn't work). This is exactly what I was hoping for!

Comment: Glad this was helpful. I hope this insight opens up the possibilities a bit more as Tableau is a much more flexible tool then how it seems on the surface.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your Dimension of Days contains values like "Day 1", "Day 2", etc.

You can create a calculated field as follows:

```
case [Day]
WHEN "Day 1" THEN #2018-01-01#
WHEN "Day 2" THEN #2018-01-02#
WHEN "Day 3" THEN #2018-01-03#
WHEN "Day 4" THEN #2018-01-04#
WHEN "Day 5" THEN #2018-01-05#
WHEN "Day 6" THEN #2018-01-06#
WHEN "Day 7" THEN #2018-01-07#
WHEN "Day 8" THEN #2018-01-08#
WHEN "Day 9" THEN #2018-01-09#
WHEN "Day 10" THEN #2018-01-10#
WHEN "Day 11" THEN #2018-01-11#
WHEN "Day 12" THEN #2018-01-12#
end
```

Tableau uses the # around text to convert the value to a Date type.

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is what I did, but obviously has limitations (if the experiment had more than 31 days, for example). Also, I'm not a fan of dummy data - it works in this case, but I was hoping to avoid it.